# Desestructurar un valor dinámico en Javascript

Tags: javascript, objeto

Estoy consumiendo una API de paises. Ingreso el pais en un input y se me devuelve todos los datos. Entre esos datos esta el siguiente:

```js
 data = {
        "currencies": {
            "CLP": {
                name: "pais",
                valor: "50"
            }
        }
    }
```

Estoy desestructurando los valores que necesito, pero al momento de desestructurar este, no se me ocurre como. El "CLP" varia del pais que se ingresa, si ingreso Perú, en ves de CLp saldrá PEN. Necesito extraer `name` y valor.
Hasta el momento llevo esto:

```js
const { currencies} = data;
   
const {CLP:otro} = data.currencies;

const {} = data.currencies;
```

Pero claro, ninguna funciona. ¿ Como puedo indicar que esa clave/key será dinámica y poder extraer los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes la certeza de que siempre es el único dato que te trae en currencies, lo puedes hacer así:

```js
const data = {
  currencies: {
    CLP: {
      name: "pais",
      valor: "50"
    }
  }
};
    
let key = Object.keys(data.currencies)[0];
let { [key]: otro } = data.currencies;

console.log(otro);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas aplicar la desestructuración con valores dinámicos según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#nombres_de_propiedades_de_objetos_calculados_y_desestructuraci%C3%B3n) puedes realizarlo de la siguiente forma, usando el clásico `clave:valor`.

```js
data = {
    "currencies": {
        "CLP": {
            name: "pais",
            valor: "50"
        },"PEN": {
            name: "pais",
            valor: "23"
        },"USD": {
            name: "pais",
            valor: "12"
        },
    }
}

let valorDinamico = 'USD';
const {[valorDinamico]: dataDinamica} = data.currencies;
console.log(dataDinamica);
```